# Standalone git binary on server with repository viewer

Tags: linux, git, 64-bit, self-hosting

I have a server from my company.
On this server is git **not installed** *(and it will not be in the near future)*.
(On many free server hosting sites, git is also not installed)

> Is there a way to use a git binary without having git installed
>   (therefore without the needed dependencies in another folder, standalone)?

*Another server is no option for me.*

*I want git for a web git repository viewer, which of course need the git binary working in any folder, maybe there is a web git repository viewer with integrated git binary.*

---

I tried:

The server os is linux 64 Bit.
I have copied the git binary from local linux to the executable path on the server.
It did not work.
So I look up the dependencies. These libraries are needed:

- libz.so.1
- libresolv.so.2
- libpthread.so.0
- libpcre.so.3
- libc.so.6

They are only links to libraries named:

- libz.so.1.2.7
- libresolv-2.17.so
- libpthread-2.17.so
- libpcre.so.3.13.1
- libc-2.17.so

So I renamed the libraries and copied them to the server where the git binary lies. But unfortunately the git binary looks in the /lib/linux-64-gnu... os folder for the libraries, not in the same folder. I have no idea what to try next.

Comment: You should search for "build static git", you'll find quite a lot of info.

Comment: Note that git is not a single binary. In the somewhat dated Ubuntu Lucid I happen to use in this moment I have
"dpkg-query -L git-core | xargs file | grep ELF | wc -l" resulting to
121. 
I'm quite sure you can set a global linker option to build all binaries staticly linked, but I don't have time to try it myself.

Comment: In a situation like this I would probably turned to [Fossil](http://www.fossil-scm.org) because it's a) truly self-hosting; b) could be built to depend only on `libc` (a more "standard" build would make it depend on `libc`, `libz` and `libssl`). (And no, I prefer Git but in the field of being a self-hosted single binary DVCS solution Fossil wins everyone hands down.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is my solution:**

1. I downloaded and installed Ubuntu 13 on my Windows PC with the same architecture as the server I want to copy the standalone git binary. Architecture is x86_64 which stands for 64 bit. Download link is http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop
2. I burned it to a disk, booted from CD. Then I the username was 'Ubuntu', but I needed another one, so I installed Ubuntu on a USB-Stick 32GB.
3. I downloaded a git tarball file: 'git-1.7.3.tar.bz2' and extracted it with the command 'tar -jxvf git-1.7.3.tar.bz2' in Terminal after used the command 'cd ~/Downloads' to get to the directory, where the downloaded tarball git file is. Download link is code.google.com/p/kakola/downloads/detail?name=git-1.7.3.5.tar.bz2&can=2&q= (found it with googling 'git .tar.bz2')
4. Now there is a directory beside the .tar.bz2 file, go into it with 'cd git-1.7.3.5'
5. Just to make sure I installed every command mentioned from other websites that could be useful with 'sudo apt-get install libexpat1-dev asciidoc libz-dev gettext curl'
6. I created a directory at the path, where the bin should be on the server, because I only have home access it must be in the home folder, with 'mkdir /home/git'
7. Then I used the command './configure --prefix=/home/git/BIN CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} -static" NO_OPENSSL=1 NO_CURL=1' to fill the extracted folder with my config file: 'config.mak.autogen'
8. After that I made 'make' and then 'make doc' to create the files and then 'install' and 'make install-doc' and the directory I wanted the git binary filled up with all these files (pretty big 364MB on the stick)
9. Downloaded Gitlist and uploaded it to my server and uploaded the whole created Folder with all its binaries into the gitlist folder.
10. Changed the config.ini from Gitlist to use the standalone binary of git, instead of some PATH (also changed the projects path)

Gitlist finds the repository and shows it in the list view

(With GitWeb I got an error, but GitList seems OK)

Comment: I have never used gitlist. Your build steps look OK, but I'd still suggest first you make sure that your git binaries actually work. Follow a git tutorial, e.g the commands `git init`, `git add <file>`, `git status`, `git commit`, `git diff`. If they all work nicely start configuring gitlist.